# Call specific method from parent class in multiple inheritance - Python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I have one class with multiple inheritance. I would like to concat the output from some parents' methods that share the same name. Ideally, I would be able to do this without going through all parent class but selecting explicitly the cases I want.

```py
class my_class1:
    def common_method(self): return ['dependency_1']

class my_class2:
    def common_method(self): return ['dependency_2']

class my_class3:
    def whatever(self): return 'ANYTHING'

class composite(my_class1, my_class2, my_class3):
    def do_something_important(self):
        return <my_class1.common_method()> + <my_class2.common_method()>
```

Comment: Given this structure, why is it necessary for `composite` to be a subclass of any of the other classes?

Comment: Use composition, not inheritance

Comment: You *could* write `super(composite, self).common_method() + super(my_class1, self).common_method()`, but this is brittle, and the problem could be an indication that you haven't designed your classes properly.

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to define a subclass of, say, `my_class1` in order to change the name of `common_method`, and have `composite` inherit from that instead of from `my_class1` directly.

Comment: @tzaman I have it has subclasses because the composite is conceptually a derivation of both others and they do share some parts, so I thought I should show their relationship somehow.

Comment: I actually went for the composition as @Tom McLean suggested, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want to use the langage mechanisms to call super-methods (which are designed to go through all the methods in the superclasses, even ones that are not known at the time the code is written), just call the methods explicitly on the classes you want - by using the class name.

The only thing different that has to be done is that you have to call the method from the *class*, not from the *instance*, and then insert the instance manually as first parameter. Python's automatic `self` reference is only good when calling the method in the most derived sub-class (from which point, in a more common design, it will use `super` to run its counterparts in the superclasses)

For your example to work, you simply have to write it like this:

```
class my_class1:
    def common_method(self): return ['dependency_1']

class my_class2:
    def common_method(self): return ['dependency_2']

class my_class3:
    def whatever(self): return 'ANYTHING'

class composite(my_class1, my_class2, my_class3):
    def do_something_important(self):
        return my_class1.common_method(self) + my_class2.common_method(self)
```

Note, however, that if any of the `common_methods` would call `super().common_method` in a  common ancestor base, that super-method would be run once for each explicit invocation of a sub-class' `.common_method`.
If you would want to specialize *that* it would be tough to do.

In other words, if you want, a "super" counterpart that would allow you to specify which super-classes to visit when calling the method, and ensure any super-method called by those would run only once - that is feasible, but complicated and error prone. If you can use explicit classes like in this example, it is 100 times simpler.

Comment: You could also do `super`'s job and go through `__mro__` manually, but less manually than your example.

Comment: That is hard to to right. What if there are A -> B -> (C1, C2)  -> D,-> E each one calling `super()` but you don´t want the method to run both in C1 and C2, just C1, decided in the code at E, and all of then use `super` themselves (even if they all use your super() counterpart)

Comment: I meant to implement it in one place, in `composite`. Then there shouldn't be any ambiguity unless you want to skip some elements

Comment: if one does not want to skip elements, the way to go is to use `super()` properly. Calling manually things following the `__mro__` , OTOH, won´t work if any of the methods called uses `super` itself - at best, some of the methods on the superclasses will run more than once.